# catergory for global objectForKey: safety

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

We have had countless problems with JSON feeds causing `[__NSCFString objectForKey:]` errors when processed (using AFNetworking JSON Framework) that crash the application.

We are aware why this is, since a string takes up the place where an `NSDictionary` is expected.

But I was thinking, isn't it possible to make a category or subclass of the `objectForKey` function that makes a quick check to see if the object in question is a Dictionary at all ? Same thing would be lovely to have on `ObjectForKey` on `NSArray`s.

This would definately reduce the risk of problems like this reoccurring in our projects.

Comment: why not check the type using `isKindOfClass` first?

Comment: I do that on my "usual suspects" but would be preferrable (and much less messy) to have it sort of folded inside the objectForKey: function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it would be too hard to have a few functions like...

```
- (NSString*)stringForKey:(id)key;
```

You could do something like...

```
- (NSString*)stringForKey:(id)key
{
    id object = [self objectForKey:key];

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        return (NSString*)object;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

You could have similar ones for other object types too.

That way you always receive the type of object you are expecting or nil.

**EDIT**

In fact, after doing some searching. I think this function already exists for NSDictionary. (Correction thanks to jrturton. This exists only for NSUserDefaults.)

Comment: It exists for NSUserDefaults, not NSDictionary.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I agree. I've often come across the same problem of using objectForKey and then failing because it's the wrong type.